# How to delete a snapshot in Symfony Cloud Project?

Tags: symfony, symfony5

How to delete a snapshot in Symfony Cloud Project ? There is commands like symfony env:snapshot:create

but there is no "env:snapshot:delete --snaphot-id" Any idea ?

Comment: Hi Gilles, you will have better chances to find support on the Symfony slack and its #symfonycloud channel.

Comment: Documentation said: Snapshots are guaranteed to be kept for at least 7 days. 
So I guess that if snapshots are removable, they cannot be guaranteed to be kept.